# O que é exatamente o Proxy do SET_PROXY do UTL_HTTP (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, http-request, oracle11g

utl_http.set_proxy(http://pgau:abcd@123@102.168.12.12:5678');

Neste exemplo o que exatamente este endereço de Proxy ?

Tentei o IP interno e não funcionou , a infra da minha empresa disse não ter "proxy externo".

[Fonte](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1126855)

Grato.

Answer (score 2):

Como o pacote `utl_http` é usado para acessar dados através da Internet, se você estiver acessando a Internet através de um *proxy*, numa empresa por exemplo onde isso é bem comum, os comandos do `utl_http` vão falhar, porque eles tentam acessar a rede diretamente.

Então o `set_proxy` serve para informar ao pacote `utl_http` as configurações de *proxy* para que ele consiga acessar a rede, como endereço do servidor de *proxy* e as credenciais de autenticação (usuário e senha), só isso.

O formato mais comum é `tul_http.set_proxy('http://102.168.12.12:5678')`, ou seja, o endereço (pode ser IP) e a porta, quando não há autenticação.

Se houver autenticação, precisa informar usuário e senha antes, do endereço, separado por arroba: `utl_http.set_proxy('http://usuario:senha@102.168.12.12:5678')`

Exemplos daqui: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1126855

**EDIT:** no seu exemplo: `http://pgau:abcd@123@102.168.12.12:5678'`, significa:

> usuário: pgau
>   senha: abcd
>   servidor proxy: 102.168.12.12
>   porta: 5678

Se não tiver um *proxy*, não é necessário fazer essa configuração

Comment: Grato , vou testar e dou retorno aqui.

Comment: Esbarrei no hptts , precisa instalar um componente wallet , como apenas ia replicar uma função já existente parei por hora.